# Python - Input Menu Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python and I am trying to make a little adventure game, just to develop my skills. So, for my game, I want there to be a few options, and the player will pick one and it will return a different result. However, the options will not always be the same, so I decided to make a function, so the options and results could differ. Here is the code for my function:

```
def action(act1, act2, act3, act4):
loop = True
while loop:
    print(menu)
    player_action = input("Where would you like to go? ")

    if player_action == '1':
        act1
        return

    elif player_action == '2':
        act2
        return

    elif player_action == '3':
        act3
        return

    elif player_action == '4':
        act4
        return

    else:
        print("Please type \'1\', \'2\', \'3\', or \'4\'")
```

The parameters are functions for what I want to print out.

My problem is, when I call this function and run the code, Python executes each function in every if and elif statement. For example, when I call this:

```
def home_act1():
    print("Welcome to the wilderness!")

def home_act2():
    print("Welcome to the town!")


def home_act3():
    print("Welcome to the store!")


def home_act4():
    print("You left the adventure.")
    exit()


action(home_act1(), home_act2(), home_act3(), home_act4())
```

I run the program and it does this:
Welcome to the wilderness!
Welcome to the town!
Welcome to the store!
You left the adventure.

Process finished with exit code 0

It seems to just be running all four of my parameters, it worked before I made it a function but something isn't working right.

Thanks to any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
action(home_act1(), home_act2(), home_act3(), home_act4())
```

you are actually calling each function and passing the result (`None` in each case, since that is the default.

Try passing just the functions (`home_act` instead of `home_act()`), then in the loop body actually call `act()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def home_act1():
    print("Welcome to the wilderness!")

def home_act2():
    print("Welcome to the town!")


def home_act3():
    print("Welcome to the store!")


def home_act4():
    print("You left the adventure.")
    exit()



def action():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        # print(menu)
        player_action = input("Where would you like to go? ")

        if player_action == '1':
            return home_act1() #or you can remove the return and carry on in the function

        elif player_action == '2':
            return home_act2()

        elif player_action == '3':
            return home_act3()
        elif player_action == '4':
            return home_act4()

        else:
            print("Please type \'1\', \'2\', \'3\', or \'4\'")

action()
```

You can return a function call:

```
def functionToCall():
    print('Ok function called')

def function():
    return functionToCall()

function()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have all 4 outputs and then the code exiting is because you call all four `home_act` functions immediately by doing `action(home_act1(), home_act2(), home_act3(), home_act4())`, which executes one after another and exits the program due to the `exit()` in `home_act4()`.

Another thing that is problematic is that you `return` after each action within the while-loop, which means the code would have stopped once the user has done one single action.

Fixing these problems results in the following code:

```
def action():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        #print(menu)
        player_action = input("Where would you like to go? ")

        if player_action == '1':
            home_act1()  # call the respective action function here

        elif player_action == '2':
            home_act2()

        elif player_action == '3':
            home_act3()

        elif player_action == '4':
            home_act4()

        else:
            print("Please type \'1\', \'2\', \'3\', or \'4\'")

def home_act1():
    print("Welcome to the wilderness!")

def home_act2():
    print("Welcome to the town!")

def home_act3():
    print("Welcome to the store!")

def home_act4():
    print("You left the adventure.")
    exit()


action()
```

Good luck with further coding :)